# Dynamically generating variable names to be used in the bind_param() function of a PHP prepared statement

Tags: php

I was wondering if it's possible to store the variables to be inserted in a `bind_param()` function *inside another variable* such that if this were the original query:

```
$stmt->bind_param("si", $column1, $column2);
```

would it be possible to store the 2 variables inside another variable, i.e:

```
$columns = $column1.','.$column2;
```

And then if the new variable can be used inside the `bind_param()` function like this such that it works:

```
$stmt->bind_param("si", $columns);
```

My Database column names and php variable names are the same (except for the '$' sign of course), so I tried this:

```
$string = "column1, column2";

function convert_to_variables($string) {

        // Convert column names to an array
        $array = explode(", ", $string); 

        // Convert column names array values to a variable
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            $array_values_with_dollar[] = $$value; // (previously tried with '$'.$value)
        }

        // Convert to string again
        $imploded = implode(", ", $array_values_with_dollar); 

        return $imploded;
}

.
.
$variables = convert_to_variables($string);
.
.
$stmt->bind_param("si", $variables );
.
.
// Everything else like $stmt = $dbc->prepare(""); and $stmt->execute(); etc exists. 
// The bind_param() is the only line with an error.
```

(Right now I'm getting an '*Undefined variable: column1*' error.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to do with strings directly, because it'd be interpreted as just that - a single string, and not a combination of strings that'd make up the values for each column. Using that logic, you'd also have issues if one of your strings actually contains `', '`as well - then it wouldn't match up with number of values and number of parameters.

I can suggest an alternative using arrays instead. You can use that string as a base if you really need to, and use `explode()` on that. In any case, using an array, you can use the "unpacking operator" `...` to unpack the array.

```
$string = "column1, column2";
$boom = explode(", ", $string);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", ...$boom);
```

Alternatively build it as an array, and use that (which effectively is the same). **This approach is better**, as it will not produce more values than parameters if one or more of the strings contains a comma `,`.

```
$variables = array("column1", "column2");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", ...$variables);
```

- [PHP 'New Features' on array unpacking](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat)

Also note that I've changed "types" parameter to `ss` (was `si`), because both your parameters are in fact strings.

Comment: Thanks, I'll just go through the array unpacking stuff and get back. And in fact this is how my _bind_param()_ looks like at the moment: _bind_param("issssssssiissisiddiissssssss", ... )_ :/ Which is why I didn't want to write  down all those variable names.

Comment: It's possible to build the type-parameter dynamically as well, but at least the splat-operator (or array-unpacking as I've written in the answer) makes the argument-listing way easier. It's not an operator that's well documented, or well known - but it certainly has its uses ;-)

Comment: Thanks a million for the unpacking/splat operator. I finally figured out how to get my code working :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? Creates variables called $column1 , 2 etc. From string.

```
$string = "column1, column2, boo3";

$arr = explode(", ", $string);

Foreach($arr as $var){
    $$var = $var;
}

Echo $column1 . $column2 . $boo3;
```

https://3v4l.org/sW0cu
Double `$` will grab the variables value and use that as name for the variable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I guess my issue is more with the bind_param() not accepting a variable **which contains all the other variables** that goes inside it. : /